# Three.js: Model is not shown when switching multiple layers, but visible when break points are activated

Tags: three.js

I'm relatively new to three.js and I ran into the following problem: I have 10 different versions of a obj file, that represent a mesh object at different points of time. To now simulate movement of my object I want to show these models in sequence and hide the other ones.
In order to do that I loaded my models in different layers which I then toggle on and off and go back to the original model in the end. After animating the changes I made sure to set a waiting time to be able to actually see the changes. When I set a breakpoint in my code for example at animate(); I see the different layers switching exactly like I planed it.
But when I just run the code without breakpoints my model disappears from the scene and then after sometime I see the original model. In the task manager I can see that the gpu performance goes down to about 0% as soon as I run this code, when I only show the model without switching layers it's at about 20-30%. I have the same problem in chrome, edge and firefox browsers. There is no error message.

I'm unsure how much code I should share so I'm sorry if it is too much. As I had problems with the gpu before I explicitly assigned it.

```
type here<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>

        
        <div id="container"></div>


        <script type="module">

            import Stats from 'three/addons/libs/stats.module.js';
            import { GUI } from 'three/addons/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js';
            import { OBJLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
            
            let scene, renderer, camera; 
            let mixer, settings, stats; 
            let root_folder, file_name, file;
            let i, files_array;
            const objLoader = new OBJLoader();
            
            
            
                root_folder = '/obj_files/';
                
                files_array_name= ['name0.obj', 'name1.obj', 'name2.obj', 'name3.obj', 'name4.obj', 'name5.obj', 'name6.obj',
                            'name7.obj', 'name8.obj', 'name9.obj'];
                            
            init();
            function init() {

                const container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
                

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.set( 1, 4, -10);
                camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );
                camera.layers.enable( 0 ); 
                camera.layers.enable( 1 );
                camera.layers.enable( 2 );
                camera.layers.enable( 3 ); 
                camera.layers.enable( 4 );
                camera.layers.enable( 5 );
                camera.layers.enable( 6 );
                camera.layers.enable( 7 );
                camera.layers.enable( 8 );
                camera.layers.enable( 9 );
                
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
                scene.add( ambientLight );

                const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
                camera.add( pointLight );
                scene.add( camera );
                pointLight.layers.enable( 0 );
                pointLight.layers.enable( 1 );
                pointLight.layers.enable( 2 );
                pointLight.layers.enable( 3 );
                pointLight.layers.enable( 4 );
                pointLight.layers.enable( 5 );
                pointLight.layers.enable( 6 );
                pointLight.layers.enable( 7 );
                pointLight.layers.enable( 8 );
                pointLight.layers.enable( 9 );
            
                //here the original model is loaded and createPanel is called
            
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                
                renderer.domElement.id = 'canvas';
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('webgpu', {
                  powerPreference: 'high-performance',
                  gpuVendor: 'gpu',
                  failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat: false,
                });
            
                
                }

            function createPanel() {
                const panel = new GUI( { width: 310 } ); 
                const folder16 = panel.addFolder('Movement');               
                settings = {'move': false}; 
                folder16.add( settings, 'Movement' ).onChange(move);
            }

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
            
            function move(){
                for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {
                            const my_layer = (i+1);                         
                            file = root_folder + files_array[i];
                            const modelData = objLoader.loadAsync(file);
                            modelData.then((modelData) => {
                                var mesh = modelData.children[0];
                                mesh.material = new    THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: #000000});
                                scene.add(mesh);
                                mesh.layers.set( my_layer );
                                camera.layers.disableAll();
                                if (i==9)
                                {
                                 (change_layers());
                                }
                            });
                }       
            }
            
            function change_layers() {
                for (let i = 1; i <11; i++){
                    if(i >1)
                        {camera.layers.toggle(i-1);}
                    camera.layers.toggle(i);
                    animate();
                    sleep(10000);
                    if(i ==10)
                    {
                        camera.layers.toggle(10);
                        camera.layers.toggle(0);
                        animate();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            function sleep(milliseconds) {
              var start = new Date().getTime();
              for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
                if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
                  break;
                }
              }
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are a number of concerns here, including the spin-wait in your custom sleep() method, but you're mixing a frame-independent animation loop with on-demand rendering.  Without your models or a minimally-working example, I'd start by removing the RAF call altogether and see if/how the behavior changes.

Comment: Okay, so I moved the loading function into init() as the animation can only be started in the panel after everything is loaded. And I took out the sleep function and replaced it with setTimeout(animate(), 1000);. But it's not waiting at all. The model doesn't disappear anymore but apparently it's just racing through the animation. Any idea how I can slow that down?